# How can we override config in .Net framework for integration tests?

Tags: .net, integration-testing, .net-4.8

I am trying to use a different test database for the execution of integration tests for my application which in .net framework 4.8
Using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

Trying to find a way to change API connection string while executing int tests as API is pointing to the original db.

Is it possible to tell the API to use integration tests config or connection string while executing those tests?

This is how my client is setup

```
public static HttpResponseMessage WebApiGet(string path, string mediaType = "application/json")
{
    var handler = new WebRequestHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
    var virtualDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VirtualDirectory"];
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InternalBaseAddress"]);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(mediaType));
        return client.GetAsync($"{virtualDirectory}{path}")
            .Result;
    }
}
```

sample int test

```
    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("IntegrationTest")]
    [TestCategory("House")]
    public async Task GetHOuseDetails_ShouldReturn200AndCorrectHOuseDetails()
    {

        var server = TestServer.Create<Startup>();

        //Act
        var response = WebApiHelper.WebApiGet($"/api/house/details/{777777}");

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessStatusCode, "Get House Details fail");

        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HouseDetails>(content);

        Assert.AreEqual(777777, result.Id);
    }
```

int test connection string in app.config
[image]

API startup file

```
using Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle;
using Castle.Windsor;
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.Dashboard;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Jet2.Memphis.Internal.Api.Startup))]

namespace House.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Map Dashboard to the `http://<your-app>/hangfire` URL.
            app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions()
            {
                Authorization = new[]
                {
                    new AllowAllDashboardAuthorizationFilter()
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public class AllowAllDashboardAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private IUserManager _userManager;
        private IWindsorContainer _container;

        public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
        {
            _container = ContainerManager.Container;

            using (_container.BeginScope())
            {
                _userManager = _container.Resolve<IUserManager>();

                return _userManager.HasPageAccess("hangfiredashboard");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

API endpoint

```
private readonly IMediator _mediator;
    [Route("api/house/details/{id}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetHouseDetails(int id)
    {
        var result = await _mediator.Send(new GetHouseDetailsQuery
        {
            HouseId = id
        });

        if (result != null)
            return Ok(result);

        return NotFound();
    }
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, but without showing how your code and tests are setup we can't help

Comment: What configuration do you refer to? And what do you mean by `integration testing`? If you mean `app.config`  and tests run using eg NUnit, the config files used are those of the test runner. The test library may allow using test-specific config files. For example [NUnit allows this](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/technical-notes/usage/Configuration-Files.html?q=configuration) if the config file is named after the test assemlty, eg `mytests.dll` and `mytests.dll.config`

Comment: Sorry added more details @Dawood Awan

Comment: okay It seems like you are using Mediator and want to inject the correct DbContext into the `GetHouseDetailsQuery`. An example of such configuration can be found here: https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/blob/main/tests/Application.IntegrationTests/CustomWebApplicationFactory.cs

As you can see from the code, the default Dependency Injection config is removed and a new one is created using appsettings.json config from the Integration Tests project.

Comment: I am seeing issue while installing package for WebApplicationFactory- Installing "Microsoft. AspNetCore Mvc Testing’ failed.

‘Additional information: Could not install package
“Microsoft AspNetCoreMvcTesting 7.0.2. You are trying to install this
package into a project that targets “NETFramework Version= v4.8; but
the package does not contain any assembly references or content files
that are compatible with that framework. For more information.
‘contact the package author.